# Batch fetching messages performance

Tags: gmail-api

I need to get the last 100 messages in the INBOX (headers only). For that I'm currently using the IMAP extension to search and then fetch the messages. This is done with two requests (`SEARCH` and then `UID FETCH`).
**What's the Gmail API equivalent to fetching multiple messages in one request?**
All I could find is a batch API, which seems way more cumbersome (composing a long list of `messages:get` requests wrapped in plain HTTP code).

Comment: Just small addition to @walty yeung's ans. We need to perform `batch.execute()` before second loop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's pretty much the same in the Gmail API as in IMAP. Two requests: first is messages.list to get the message ids.  Then a (batched) message.get to retrieve the ones you want.  Depending on what language you're using the client libraries may help with the batch request construction.

> A batch request is a single standard HTTP request containing multiple Google Cloud Storage JSON API calls, using the multipart/mixed content type. Within that main HTTP request, each of the parts contains a nested HTTP request.

From: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/batch

It's really not that hard, took me about an hour to figure it out in python even without the python client libraries (just using httplib and mimelib).

Here's a partial code snippet of doing it, again with direct python.  Hopefully it makes it clear that's there's not too much involved:

```
msg_ids = [msg['id'] for msg in body['messages']]
headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/mixed; boundary=%s' % self.BOUNDARY

post_body = []
for msg_id in msg_ids:
  post_body.append(
    "--%s\n"
    "Content-Type: application/http\n\n"
    "GET /gmail/v1/users/me/messages/%s?format=raw\n"
    % (self.BOUNDARY, msg_id))
post_body.append("--%s--\n" % self.BOUNDARY)
post = '\n'.join(post_body)
(headers, body) = _conn.request(
    SERVER_URL + '/batch',
    method='POST', body=post, headers=headers)
```

Comment: getting error `"self" is not defined`. Can you give a more complete code example, please?

Answer (score 8):

Great reply!
If somebody wants to use a raw function in php to make batch requests for fetching emails corresponding to message ids, please feel free to use mine.

```php
function perform_batch_operation($auth_token, $gmail_api_key, $email_id, $message_ids, $BOUNDARY = "gmail_data_boundary"){
    $post_body = "";
    foreach ($message_ids as $message_id) {
        $post_body .= "--$BOUNDARY\n";
        $post_body .= "Content-Type: application/http\n\n";
        $post_body .= 'GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/'.$email_id.
                '/messages/'.$message_id.'?metadataHeaders=From&metadataHeaders=Date&format=metadata&key='.urlencode($gmail_api_key)."\n\n";
    }
    $post_body .= "--$BOUNDARY--\n";

    $headers = [ 'Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary='.$BOUNDARY, 'Authorization: OAuth '.$auth_token  ];

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/batch' );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT , 60 ) ;
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60 ) ;
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS , $post_body);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    $tmp_response =  curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $tmp_response;

}
```

FYI the above function gets just the headers for the emails, in particular the From and Date fields, please adjust according to the api documentation https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get

Answer (score 7):

In addition to MaK you can perform multiple batch requests using the [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) and [`Google_Http_Batch()`](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/f9e79bdaa2140e21522d58549e3e9864c9fb4d7c/examples/batch.php)

```
        $optParams = [];
        $optParams['maxResults'] = 5;
        $optParams['labelIds'] = 'INBOX'; // Only show messages in Inbox
        $optParams['q'] = 'subject:hello'; // search for hello in subject

        $messages = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($email_id,$optParams);

        $list = $messages->getMessages();

            $client->setUseBatch(true);

            $batch = new Google_Http_Batch($client);                

            foreach($list as $message_data){

                $message_id = $message_data->getId();

                $optParams = array('format' => 'full');

                $request = $service->users_messages->get($email_id,$message_id,$optParams);

                $batch->add($request, $message_id);                 
            }

            $results = $batch->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

here is the python version, using the official [google api client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/batch). Note that I did not use the callback here, because I need to handle the responses in a synchronous way.

```py
from apiclient.http import BatchHttpRequest
import json

batch = BatchHttpRequest()

#assume we got messages from Gmail query API
for message in messages:
    batch.add(service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id'],
                                             format='raw'))
batch.execute()
for request_id in batch._order:
    resp, content = batch._responses[request_id]
    message = json.loads(content)
    #handle your message here, like a regular email object
```

Answer (score 2):

solution from Walty Yeung is worked partially for my use case.
if you guys tried the code and nothing happens use this batch

```
batch = service.new_batch_http_request()
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Walty Yeung's answer is outdated and returns the error `googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/batch returned "Not Found">`