# How to do Google API batch request using python httplib or urllib2?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, batch-processing, urllib, httplib

After the user authorizes the 'read' permission, I need to fetch all the emails of the user. I have access_token/refresh_token which help me to make individual calls for each email. I want to do batch request for all message_ids to reduce the time involved. Here goes my code for batch request which fails.

```
import httplib,urllib

def fetch_batch():
    headers = {'Authorization' : 'Bearer ya29.swCasdjkfgsdalkfgsadfgasdjhgasdkjfasgdfaksdf', 'Host' : 'www.googleapis.com', 'Content-Type' : 'multipart/mixed; boundary=demoabc_wp'}

    body="""demoabc_wp
    Content-Type: application/http

    GET /gmail/v1/users/uabc.kp1@gmail.com/messages/1497474ajsd

    demoabc_wp
    Content-Type: application/http

    GET /gmail/v1/users/uabc.kp1@gmail.com/messages/149744safdg

    demoabc_wp
    """
    h = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.googleapis.com')
    h.request('POST', '/batch', body, headers)
    print h.getresponse().read()
```

This gives this as response:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
    <H1>Bad Request</H1>
    <H2>Error 400</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Thanks in advance.
Refer from : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch and [Batch fetching messages performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439764/batch-fetching-messages-performance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You messed up the multipart encoding.  Try

```
import httplib,urllib

def fetch_batch():
    headers = {'Authorization' : 'Bearer ya29.swCasdjkfgsdalkfgsadfgasdjhgasdkjfasgdfaksdf', 'Host' : 'www.googleapis.com', 'Content-Type' : 'multipart/mixed; boundary=demoabc_wp'}

    body="""--demoabc_wp
Content-Type: application/http

GET /gmail/v1/users/uabc.kp1@gmail.com/messages/1497474ajsd

--demoabc_wp
Content-Type: application/http

GET /gmail/v1/users/uabc.kp1@gmail.com/messages/149744safdg

--demoabc_wp--
"""
    h = httplib.HTTPSConnection('www.googleapis.com')
    h.request('POST', '/batch', body, headers)
    print h.getresponse().read()
```

Note, it is 2 hyphens at the start of any boundary, and 2 additional hyphens at the end if it is the last boundary

Comment: I think you should try using the code to make a request. It is a 400 error. Although I used the exact syntax you suggested but still it shows a 400 error. There is something else I am missing I think.

Comment: 2 Issues, needs to be https, and spaces before things in the body breaks stuff.  Above works, except for complaining cause that's not a valid authorization.  Note, even with those fixes, it still needs the hyphens

Answer (score 1):

The Google APIs Python Client Library provides [built-in support for batch requests](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/batch), and should be an easier solution to maintain in the long run.